# Why are these two values different when I assign one to the other?

Tags: python

The code below gives different values for c and d when I print them

> ```
> import csv
>
> datafile = open('test1.csv', 'r')
> datareader = csv.reader(datafile)
> c = []
> for row in datareader:
>     c.append(row)
>
> d = [[0]*2]*2
> i=0
>
> while i < 2:
>
>     j=0
>
>     while j < 2:
>
>         d[i][j] = float(c[i][j])
>
>         j=j+1
>     i=i+1
>
> print(c)
> print(d)
> ```

Comment: Can you provide example output?

Comment: It really depends on the contents of test1.csv. What are the results? How do those values differ?

Comment: Hmm it's probably because they are in fact different, please provide some more information, for example what is in the csv.

Answer (score 7):

This line:

```
d = [[0]*2]*2
```

doesn't create copies of the inner lists, it just creates multiple references to the same list. Replace it with an explicit declaration:

```
d = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Comment: thanks, the example I showed in my question was a condensed version of the actual problem. In my actual code d = [[0]*40]*1000. Is there a simpler way to do the explicit declaration for the 40x1000 list?

Comment: `[[0 for i in range(40)] for j in range(1000)]`

Answer (score 1):

Lists are mutable elements. You're not creating multiple lists when you do things like `[[0]]*10` but creates 10 references to the same object.